# How would I create a new variable or object while the program is running? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, variables, object

I'm very new to C++ and programming in general, so I was looking for simple scenarios to test myself. I wanted to make a program that would allow a user to input basic data for characters in a game, but I realized that I had no way of allowing the user to enter the amount of characters that they want. They would be limited to the one I currently had allowed. My question is this: how would, on a user finishing one character and ready to create another, what kind of code would I use to generate another object of the class? Here's my code if none of that made any sense at all:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class character {
    public:
        string name;
        string playerClass;
        int health;
};

int main() {
    character character1;

    cout << "What is your character's name?";
    cin >> character1.name;
    cout << "What class is your character?";
    cin >> character1.playerClass;
    cout << "How much health does your character have?";
    cin >> character1.health;

    //Display info, ask if user wants to make more characters.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how would, on a user finishing one character and ready to create
>   another, what kind of code would I use to generate another object of
>   the class?

Use  [`std::vector<character>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>
//...
int main() {
    std::vector<character> vCharacters;
    bool enter_more = true;

    while (enter_more)
    {
       character character1;
       cout << "What is your character's name?";
       cin >> character1.name;
       cout << "What class is your character?";
       cin >> character1.playerClass;
       cout << "How much health does your character have?";
       cin >> character1.health;

       // add new character to vector
       vCharacters.push_back(character1);

       //Display info, ask if user wants to make more characters.
       if ( !user_wants_more_input() )
           enter_more = false;
    }
    // now vCharacters has all the characters entered
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple `character`s you can use `vector<character>`,

```
int main() {
    std::vector<character> characters;
    char in = 'y';
    while (tolower(in) == 'y') {
        character c;
        cout << "What is your character's name?";
        cin >> c.name;
        cout << "What class is your character?";
        cin >> c.playerClass;
        cout << "How much health does your character have?";
        cin >> c.health;

        characters.push_back(c);

        cout << "Do you want to add another character? (Y/N) "
        cin >> in;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`#include <vector>` first to include `vector` header file.

Answer (score 0):

There are already other answers regarding what you have asked. use `std::vector` as suggested by others.

Aside from that, I am posting this answer to suggest a fix to your code.

In classes it is better if you encapsulate your variables. Try not to expose the internal variables of your class directly.

It is better to use something like this

```
class character {
private:
    string name;
    string playerClass;
    int health;
public:
    string getName(){ return name;}
    void setName(const string &_name){ name = _name;}
    string getPlayerClass(){ return playerClass;}
    void setPlayerClass(const string &_pc){ playerClass = _pc;}
    in getHealth(){ return health;}
    void setHealth(const int _h){ health = _h;}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the shared pointers,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class character {
    public:
        string name;
        string playerClass;
        int health;
//OR c++11 style
//        string name = "";
//        string playerClass = "";
//        int health = 0;

        character(): name(""),
                playerClass(""),
                health(0) {
            cout<<"Im constructed"<<endl;
        }
        ~character() { cout<<"Im destructed"<<endl; }
};

int main() {
    vector<shared_ptr<character>> cVector = {};
    shared_ptr<character> pCharacter(new character);
    cout << "What is your character's name?";
    cin >> pCharacter->name;
    cout << "What class is your character?";
    cin >> pCharacter->playerClass;
    cout << "How much health does your character have?";
    cin >> pCharacter->health;
    cVector.push_back(pCharacter);
    //Display info, ask if user wants to make more characters.

    return 0;
}
```

Note after excuting the program the destructor will be called automatically (object from the heap automatically gets deleted). you may need to compile with -std=c++11 command line for your g++ to compile this code.

Answer (score -1):

`new` is your friend.

First add a default constructor to your object, initializing all the variables.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
class character {
    public:
        string name;
        string playerClass;
        int health;
        character() {
                name = "";
                playerClass = "";
                health = 0;
        };
        ~character() {};
};
```

And in `main()`, change the first line to:

```
character * character1 = new character();
```

Then every time you make a new `character` object, use a similar line.

Edited to add:  Oops!  I've been away from raw C++ for so long that I forgot about the destructor!  I've added it into the class, assuming I remember it correctly.

Double oops:  At the end of the program, destroy the object:

```
delete character1;
```

And that's why later languages handle the memory cleanup automatically.

Comment: Feel free to point out (further) bugs in my code, so that I can fix them.

Comment: `new` should be avoided as much as possible in C++. Prefer to use objects directly (on the stack) or smart pointers.

Comment: This constructor is not needed, as `character` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization could be used. Also `name = "";` is a waste of time, `name` is already an empty string by that point. This destructor is also a bad move: there is an implicitly generated destructor already, but declaring your own causes the implicit move operations to not be defined.

Comment: @Kevin ...or a container such as `vector`

Comment: "And that's why later languages handle the memory cleanup automatically." - actually C++ cleans up automatically too, unless you specifically request that you don't want it to by writing `character * character1 = new character();` !

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the tip.  I've been in C# land for some time, and never studied smart pointers.  I keep an eye on the C++ questions just for such tips.